# Тестирование программы с++

Tags: c++

Есть простая программа с++ (пишу в Xcode) и папка с тестами (тест - текстовый файл, пример: данные - "01", ответ - "01.a"). Использовал ifstream для получения данных и ответа из файла, но приходиться постоянно менять 2 цифры в названиях файлов для перехода к следующему тесту. Как сделать быструю проверку?

Comment: Вы можете более точно сформулировать вопрос? Вам нужно перебирать файлы с числовыми именами, заполненными нулями? Есть `std::regex` (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/basic_regex) и `std::filesystem` (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/directory_iterator).

Comment: данные и ответ - числа. Пытался использовать filesystem, но там написано довольно непонятно (я пока начинающий).

Comment: @Πανμέτρονάριστον Из пушки по воробьям...

Comment: `for(int i = 0; i < ....; ++i) { char filename[10]; sprintf(filename,"%02d",i); .....}` - например, примерно так...

Comment: .Bat файл `программа имя_файла` , ... . А в программе берёте аргумент как имя файла. Этот файл и открываете.

Comment: Приведите ваш код и уточните задачу

Answer (score -1):

На самом деле часть с `filesystem` довольно проста - используем итератор и считаем имена обычных файлов, `dirpath`  тут должен содержать имя существующей папки или итератор возвратит end(),

```
// наша функция проверки соответствия имени требуемому шаблону
is_proper_filename(const std::string& fn) { 
 //... 
}

namespace fs = std::filesystem;

std::set<std::string> filenames;
```

Заполнение списка имен используя directory_entry

```
for(auto & entry: fs::directory_iterator(dirpath))
{
     if(entry.is_regular_file() && is_proper_filename(entry.path())) 
       filenames.insert(entry.path());
}
```

У нас есть отсортированный список имен, осталось только вызывать рабочую процедуру для каждого.